# upload image swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, post, service

I have this code to upload an image in swift, but not working. Any idea why it does not work?
the service will have to pass an image and json. If I pass the json works when you step the image I get internal server error

```
    let boundary = "---011000010111000001101001"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary

    let data = [MultipartElement(name: "json", disposition: "form-data", value: json)]


    let newline = "\r\n"
    var body = ""

    **Here add image**

    if let _filePath = filePath {
        let fileName = _filePath.lastPathComponent
        print("\(fileName)")
        body += "--" + boundary + newline
        body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"adjunto\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"" + newline
        body += "Content-Type: image/png" + newline + newline

        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: _filePath.path!)

        let dataPNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
        //let dataPNG = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)

        let str = dataPNG?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

        body += str!

        body += newline
    }

    **Here add params**

    for element in data {
        body += "--" + boundary + newline
        body += element.toSection()
    }

    body += "--" + boundary + "--" + newline

    let bodyData = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.setValue("\(bodyData!.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")

    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

> I use to add parameters to the body

```
struct MultipartElement {
    let name: String
    let disposition: String
    let value: String

    init (name: String, disposition: String, value: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.disposition = disposition
        self.value = value
    }

    func toSection () -> String {
        let newline = "\r\n"
        var body = ""

        body += "Content-Disposition:\(disposition); name=\"\(name)\"" + newline
        body += newline
        body += value + newline

        return body
    }
}
```

Comment: An internal server error is something to be fixed on the server. If you are just sending some illegal data format, then the server should respond accordingly with some more meaningful message or at least response code. As we do not know the server's requirements, we can hardly help at all.

Comment: ok, thank hermann klecker